# Append all files to one single file in unix and rename the output file with part of first and last filenames

Tags: linux, shell, unix

For example, I have below log files from the 16th-20th of Feb 2015. Now I want to create a single file named, `mainentrywatcherReport_2015-02-16_2015-02-20.log`. So in other words, I want to extract the date format from the first and last file of week (Mon-Fri) and create one output file every Saturday. I will be using cron to trigger the script every Saturday.

```
$ ls -l
mainentrywatcher_2015-02-16.log  
mainentrywatcher_2015-02-17.log   
mainentrywatcher_2015-02-18.log    
mainentrywatcher_2015-02-19.log  
mainentrywatcher_2015-02-20.log  

$ cat *.log >> mainentrywatcherReport_2015-02-16_2015-02-20.log  
$ mv *.log archive/
```

Can anybody help on how to rename the output file to above format?

Comment: You can use `head` and `tail` to get the first and last filenames in the directory.

Comment: `head`, `tail`, and some string manipulation (`cut` / `grep`, http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html , ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps try this:

```
parta=`ls -l | head -n1 | cut -d'_' -f2 | cut -d'.' -f1`
partb=`ls -l | head -n5 | cut -d'_' -f2 | cut -d'.' -f1`
filename=mainentrywatcherReport_${parta}_${partb}.log
cat *.log >> ${filename}
```

- "ls -l" output is described in the question
- "head -nX" takes the Xth line of the output
- "cut -d'_' -f2" takes everything (that remains) after the first underscore
- "cut -d'.' -f1" times everything (that remains) before the first period
- both commands are surrounded by ` marks (above tilde ~) to capture the output of the command to a variable
- file name assembles the two dates stripped of the unnecessary with the other formatting desired for the final file name.
- the cat command demonstrates one possible way to use the resulting filename

Happy coding! Leave a comment if you have any questions.

Comment: This is also good but for partb variable we need to have tail -n1 instead of  head -n5. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
LOGS="`echo mainentrywatcher_2[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9].log`"
HEAD=
TAIL=
for logs in $LOGS
do
    TAIL=`echo $logs | sed -e 's/^.*mainentrywatcher_//' -e 's/\.log$//'`
    test -z "$HEAD" && HEAD=$TAIL
done
cat $LOGS >mainentrywatcherReport_${HEAD}_${TAIL}.log
mv $LOGS archive/
```

That is:

- get a list of the existing logs (which happen to be sorted) in a variable $LOGS
- walk through the list, getting just the date according to the example
- save the first date as $HEAD
- save the last date as $TAIL
- after the loop, cat all of those files into the new output file
- move the used-up log-files into the archive directory.

Comment: A more complete script would check also if there *were* any files.

Comment: Hi, Thanks, your solution works but output file name is coming as mainentrywatcherReport_mainentrywatcher_2015-02-16_mainentrywatcher_2015-02-20.log but I want the name as mainentrywatcherReport_2015-02-16_2015-02-20.log, can you please suggest edit for this? I dont want second mainentrywatcher in tail variable

Comment: It was a typo - fixed.  When I reviewed the posting for typos I noticed a stray "^.*" which did not look right and "corrected" it to a glob.  That is in the line with *sed*.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this if you want to introduce simple looping...

FROM=`ls -lrt mainentrywatcher_* | awk '{print $9}' | head -1 | cut -d"_" -f2 | cut -d"." -f1`

TO=`ls -lrt mainentrywatcher_* | awk '{print $9}' | tail -1 | cut -d"_" -f2 | cut -d"." -f1`

FINAL_LOG=mainentrywatcherReport_${FROM}_${TO}.log

for i in `ls -lrt mainentrywatcher_* | awk '{print $9}'`
do
 cat $i >> $FINAL_LOG
done

echo "All Logs Stored in $FINAL_LOG"

Answer (score 0):

Another approach given your daily files and test contents as follows:

```
mainentrywatcher_2015-02-16.log  ->  a
mainentrywatcher_2015-02-17.log  ->  b
mainentrywatcher_2015-02-18.log  ->  c
mainentrywatcher_2015-02-19.log  ->  d
mainentrywatcher_2015-02-20.log  ->  e
```

That utilizes bash **parameter expansion/substring extraction** would be a simple loop:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -i cnt=0                                # simple counter to determine begin
for i in mainentrywatcher_2015-02-*; do         # loop through each matching file
    tmp=${i//*_/}                               # isolate date
    tmp=${tmp//.*/}
    [ $cnt -eq 0 ] && begin=$tmp || end=$tmp    # assign first to begin, last to end
    ((cnt++))                                   # increment counter
done

cmbfname="${i//_*/}_${begin}_${end}.log"        # form the combined logfile name

cat ${i//_*/}* > $cmbfname                      # cat all into combined name

## print out begin/end/cmbfname & contents to verify
printf "\nbegin: %s\nend  : %s\nfname: %s\n\n" $begin $end $cmbfname

printf "contents: %s\n\n" $cmbfname

cat $cmbfname

exit 0
```

**use/output:**

```
alchemy:~/scr/tmp/stack/tmp> bash weekly.sh

begin: 2015-02-16
end  : 2015-02-20
fname: mainentrywatcher_2015-02-16_2015-02-20.log

contents: mainentrywatcher_2015-02-16_2015-02-20.log

a
b
c
d
e
```

You can, of course, modify the `for loop` to accept a positional parameter containing the partial filename and pass the partial file name from the command line.